# Get periodic location updates in background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, notifications, cllocationmanager, multitasking

I'm trying to implement a feature where the user is alerted (using a `local notification`) when the distance the user has to physically travel to reach a specific geographic point (`CLLocation`), is such that he would have to leave now to reach that point at or before a specific time (`NSDate`).

I've managed to implement location updates in the background, but this leads to a problem: If the user is stationary, the delegate methods aren't called. Due to this, the `local notification` is never created.

Let's say the user has to be back at a certain place by 3.00pm, and he has chosen to be alerted 10 minutes before he has to leave to reach the destination on time. He arrives at a café at 2.00pm, where the travel time to his destination is 20 minutes. This means he wants to be notified at 2.30pm. The local notification is therefore not created at arrival, as it is still 30 minutes until he wants to be notified. Since he doesn't move while at the restaurant, the delegate never receives new updates about his location, and is therefore not able to create that notification at 2.30pm.

What I'd like to achieve is a way to call the delegate with a new location let's say every 2.5 or 5 minutes or something like that, in addition to any big changes in location. 
I've read some questions about this topic, but most seems to be targeted for iOS versions < 7, most of which doesn't work anymore.

Therefore I'm curious if anyone of you know how I can achieve this, or maybe if you have another solution that would work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you arrive at the location, you know that you'll want to notify the user in 30 minutes. So just create the notification with a fire date in 30 minutes:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:30*60];
notification.alertBody = @"You should leave now!";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Basically, you should just create a notification each time you get a location update, and cancel the previous one.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:previousNotification];
```

Comment: Great idea! I'll try to implement this :)